# Can't find package php7.0-curl

Tags: laravel, curl, homestead, php-7

I have a problem for installing `php7.0-curl` on my homestead.

On my Laravel homestead:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

It returns :

> E: Could not find package php7.0-curl
>
> E: Could not find package matching the regex « php7.0-curl »

Note: if I run in my terminal just : `curl --help` it's working.

For info, my computer runs on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid
```

Comment: Please update your questions title to English.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: yes I did. I think it's a problem of repository, but can't found it !

Comment: Does it show up when you search? apt-cache search php7

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search php7.0-curl
```

If you find it in php7.0-curl then install it using

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The package [php7.0-curl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php7.0-curl&searchon=names) is only available on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) and on Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety, to be released).

Your current version of Ubuntu, 15.04 (vivid) has [reached end of life the February 4, 2016](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-January/000203.html)

You can try to import the package from one of these distributions and resolve dependencies by hand but it would be much safer to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

By the way, if you want to install php7.0-curl inside Laravel Homestead, you need to insure that the ubuntu version running inside Laravel Homestead is greater or equal to 16.04.