# Package php7.0-curl is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server, nextcloud

EDIT : The tutorial that I was following was outdated, hense did not work. I found the solution while following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUQAWvXrtPY)

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.datamation.com/open-source/how-to-setup-your-own-cloud-server-with-nextcloud/) to install nextcloud on my homeserver.
After installing the database software, I need to install the last component - PHP.
However, after running the commands displayed on the tutorial I run into some errors :

`Package php7.0-common is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`

I already tried to find solutions but they seem outdated, that's why I raise this new topic

Thank you very much for your help.

*Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04*

While browsing solutions, I have already ran some commands to fix the problem :
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y sudo apt-get update sudo apt-cache search php7.0-curl` 
and `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551506/cant-find-package-php7-0-curl)

Comment: [related ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158446/9193372)

Comment: PHP version 7.0? In 2023? Really?

Comment: The question is what package actually contains that hard coded version number. So what command you actually executed that resulted in this message.

Comment: That tutorial is from 2017! That is SIX years ago! That was the era where dinosaurs still walked the face of the earth!

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to sound harsh. PHP 7.0 is completely outdated and actually not maintained any more. The issue in that tutorial is that it refers to hard coded version numbers which is not a good practice. You can probably see why not ;-) Instead try to refer to the version agnostic meta packages. So for example: `sudo apt-get install php-fpm php-mysql php-common ...`. Those should get resolved to the currently supported php version packaged for your distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new in this so I did not realize that the updates needed to be handled manually. Also, I found a solution that was flawless following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUQAWvXrtPY)

Comment: Well, if you explicitly tell the system to install a specific version of a package then it will do exactly that. THat tutorial you followed is a bit clumpsy in that ...